# Average of an increasing function is less than the function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be positive increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ and let $g$ equal $\frac1{x}\int_0^xf(u)du\ \ \forall x\in(0,\infty)$, then which of the following is true:

1)$g\le f\quad \forall x\in(0,\infty)$

2)$xg\le f\quad \forall x\in(0,\infty)$

3)$xg\ge f(0)\quad \forall x\in(0,\infty)$

4)$yg(x)-xg(y)\le(y-x)f(y)\quad\forall x\lt y$

I think using mean value theorem for integrals may be of some help here. But, how do we deal with inequalities? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: How exactly is 4 interpreted? Anyway, a hint is that 1 holds but 2 and 3 usually don't.

Comment: @Berci modified the question. Could you elaborate your hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1,
$f(x)-g(x)
=f(x)-\frac1{x}\int_0^xf(t)dt
=\frac1{x}\int_0^x(f(x)-f(t))dt
\gt 0$.

For 2 and 3, look at a slowly increasing function such as $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: thanks. But, what about 4)

Comment: @vidyarthi, Notice that $g$ is also increasing. Then $$yg(x)-xg(y)\leq (y-x)g(y)\leq (y-x)f(y).$$